# Are the solutions of $y''+2\gamma y'+y=0$ very different if $\gamma <1, \gamma=1,\gamma >1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I'm solving

$$y''+2\gamma y'+y=0$$

by transforming it into a system of equations with $x_1=y, x_2=y'$ and getting the system

$$x_1'=x_2\\x_2'=-2\gamma x_2-x_1$$

and forming the corresponding matrix. I find in the formula for the eigenvalues that the discriminant is $1-8\gamma$.  This comes from

$$\begin{vmatrix} -\lambda & 1\\ -2\gamma & -1-\lambda\end{vmatrix} = \lambda(1+\lambda)+2\gamma = \lambda^2 + \lambda + 2\gamma$$

which has zeroes at

$$\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1-4(2\gamma)}}{2}$$

However, I'm told in a hint that I need to consider cases $\gamma < 1, \gamma = 1, \gamma > 1$.  Yet it seems to me the relevant cases are $\gamma < 1/8$ and so on.  Did I do something wrong, or am I misunderstanding the hint?

Comment: May be your discriminant is wrong. Check it. The solution realy depends on the given three cases.

Comment: @kmitov Just updated the question with my calculation of the characteristic poly and solutions.

Comment: In your matrix you exchanged the positions of the coefficients of $x_1$ and $x_2$ in the second row. It should be $[-1,−2γ−λ]$. If it helps, re-write the second equation as $x_2'=-x_1-2γx_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct equation is $\lambda^2+2\gamma \lambda  + 1=0$.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to transform this equation into a system of equations unless you are told to or you have to solve it numerically. This is a homogeneous second-order linear equation, so we can solve it directly using the characteristic equation $m^2 + 2\gamma m + 1 = 0$, which leads to

\begin{align}m &= \frac{-2\gamma \pm \sqrt{(2\gamma)^2-4}}{2}\\
&= -\gamma \pm \sqrt{\gamma^2 - 1}\end{align}

Observe that you will get two, one, or zero real values of $\gamma$ depending on the value of the discriminant. This leads to the three cases for the solution:

Case I: $\gamma^2 > 1$. Then $y(x) = c_1e^{(-\gamma + \sqrt{\gamma^2 - 1})x} + c_2e^{(-\gamma - \sqrt{\gamma^2 - 1})x}$.

Case II: $\gamma^2 = 1$. Then $y(x) = c_1e^{-\gamma x} + c_2xe^{-\gamma x}$.

Case III: $\gamma^2 < 1$. Then $y(x) = e^{-\gamma x}(c_1 \cos (x\sqrt{1 - \gamma^2}) + c_2 \sin (x\sqrt{1 - \gamma^2}))$.

Comment: The need to transform into a system is because the prof says to.

Comment: Ah. See kmitov's answer above; your matrix is wrong. Should be
$\begin{bmatrix}
  \lambda & -1 \\
  1 & \lambda+2\gamma 
 \end{bmatrix}$.